# How do I fix Error Code -36 in Catalina?

Tags: finder, backup, error

I'm getting

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “filename” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

when I try to copy or move certain fairly old files to an external drive, and have tried both [deleting all DS_Store files](https://osxdaily.com/2012/07/05/delete-all-ds-store-files-from-mac-os-x/) and running [`dot_clean`](https://www.slrlounge.com/error-code-36-on-a-mac-what-causes-it-and-how-to-fix-it/) (with [`-mn`](https://ss64.com/osx/dot_clean.html)) with out any success.

Is there another, perhaps newer or Catalina-specific method for getting rid of Error Code -36?

Comment: @Tetsujin The target accepts other files just fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll see of someone helpful comes along. "Process of elimination" is not what I expect from SE.

Comment: Process of elimination is *how troubleshooting works.* @Tetsujin is exactly right. the dread "-36" file system error is a damaged file, possibly truncated or just mangled bits (also i/o). Without looking at the file in a hex editor it would be difficult to tell exactly what is going on here. And as we don't have our hands on the Mac the best we can do is a process of elimination.

Comment: @SteveChambers Maybe the best you can do. But is there something you’d suggest after First Aid, or is this a shell game? This happens with many files, btw; all of them fairly old.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm sorry you feel like an idiot. My intent is just to clarify whether using First Aid might fix the problem (in which case it is a potential answer, and some of the mystery shrouding it could be eliminated by posting it as such) or if it is diagnostic (in which case I'd appreciated it if you'd reveal what you think the next step might be after it fails).

Comment: The idea is that you actually *try* some of the suggestions, but as you seem reluctant, I'm done.